# IBAction and IBOutlet in Custom NSWindowController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindowcontroller

I have set up a button in my Cocoa application to open a new window. My custom window controller is declared as a property

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MyWindowController *myWindowController;
```

and when my application is launched, the controller is initialized

```
self.myWindowController = [[MyWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"myWindow"];
```

When the button is clicked, the message

```
[self.myWindowController showWindow:self];
```

is sent and the window shows up. However, when I add views to the window, I am not able to hook them up to IBOutlets and IBActions in myWindowController.

Summary: How can I set up myWindowController to handle events in myWindow?

Thanks,
Michael Knudsen

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. The object myWindowController must be set as the NIB file's owner. Click it in the Interface Builder and make the change in the Identity Inspector.